# Unable to get Angular filters working ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

So I'm working with Angular version 1.5.7 and receiving an object from the server that looks something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);function ctrl($scope){
$scope.properties.Consultants = [
    {
        text:"consultant1",
        Group: {Name:"CorporateResource", Disabled:"False"}
    },
    {
        text:"consultant2",
        Group: {Name:"CorporateResource", Disabled:"False"}
    },
    {
        type:"consultant3",
        Group: {Name:"Resource", Disabled:"False"}
    },
    {
        type:"consultant4",
        Group: {Name:"Resource", Disabled:"False"}
    }
];
```

}

and I need to filter the select list options I'm creating based based on Group.Name to only get values that have Group.Name == "CorporateProject". I've tried many variations of the following but cannot seem to get it to filter properly:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="c as c.text for c in properties.Consultants| filter:{Group.Name: 'CorporateResource'}"></select>
```

I keep getting the following js errors thrown:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had wrong filter, It should look like below

```
ng-options="c as c.text for c in properties.Consultants 
             | filter: {Group: {Name: 'CorporateResource'}}"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/20F7AEQQQtJlOYaAX76t?p=preview)

Comment: Yes! Yes! 1000x yes!! Thank you! Didn't occur to me to try this!